# Python (Discord Bot): Passing your argument to a function

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to create a discord bot which uses asyncio.
I do not understand most of the syntax, like the use of @ or the async itself, so please excuse my ignorance. I did not know how to phrase the question in Google.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands

Client = discord.Client()

bot_prefix = "&&"

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=bot_prefix)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot online")
    print("Name:", client.user.name)
    print("ID:", client.user.id)

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def ToggleSwitch(ctx):
    theSwitch = not theSwitch

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    if message.author.id == "xxxxx" and theSwitch == True:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "Switch is on and xxxxx said something")
```

I slightly oversimplified the problem, but what I would like to understand is how I would pass the `theSwitch` variable from the `ToggleSwitch` function to the `on_message`, or at least a way for myself to have variables which can be accessed throughout the code seeminglessly (perhaps by connecting to an external database?).

Again, sorry for the noobiness, but I would really like to get this out of the way, as I'm really handicapped by this issue.

Comment: if `theSwitch` is a global variable you can just access it from `on_message`, can't you?

Comment: Tried that: placed `global theSwitch` and `theSwitch = True` before all the functions, but I get an error saying `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'theSwitch' referenced before assignment`. Guessing that's an incorrect way to use them, but then what is the right way and does it work here?

Comment: well first you need to place `theSwitch = True` at the first level of indentation (not in a function), and then at the start of each function, declare `global theSwitch`

Comment: Right... That was embarrassingly simple, but either way I'm glad I understand it now. Thank you.

Comment: No problem! I'll add an answer to help future readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Variable Scoping

In this case, you want to use the global scope for `theSwitch`, meaning that that variable can be accessed from anywhere. Defining a global variable is simple; after `Client = discord.Client()` (also, you should be using `client` as a variable name), put `theSwitch = True` (or `False`).

Then, in `ToggleSwitch` (which should be named `toggleSwitch`...):

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def ToggleSwitch(ctx):
    global theSwitch
    theSwitch = not theSwitch
```

Note that you need to specify the global scope otherwise it will by default create a new local variable.

From `on_message`, you can now access `theSwitch` (though it is good to declare global scope here as well, it is not strictly necessary unless you modify `theSwitch`, which you shouldn't). Note that this method doesn't necessarily work with `async` in the odd case that two events occur at exactly the same time, but that causes undefined behaviour anyway.